# Unable to set fake-user-agent for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a Scrapy project built with Python 2.7. There are some other projects on the server as well(not Scrapy), some of them built using Python 3.5.

Now I have run into a situation where I have to set the fake-user-agent in my project for scraping some data over the web.

I installed the fake-user-agent using: `pip install scrapy-fake-useragent`
But seemingly it is installed for Python version 3.5.

Because when I try to install it again it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scrapy-fake-useragent in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Requirement already satisfied: fake-useragent in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from scrapy-fake-useragent)
```

Now how do I install it for the project I need it for? I searched for solutions over the web but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try: `pip2 install scrapy-fake-useragent`

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thanks. Wish I could upvote you :)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Post this is an answer and I will accept it.